# How to add export commands before executing in debug mode in MonoDevelop

Tags: linux, mono, monodevelop

Basically to run my software outside of MonoDevelop on Linux I use the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../../lib
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=../../lib
mono ./bin/Debug/Testbox.exe
```

And of course when I run the program in debug mode in MonoDevelop's IDE I get a DllNotFoundException because it can't load the dll in those export parameters.

I've tried adding those two lines as Environment Variables in MonoDevelop's Project "Options" but with no luck. I'm sure this must be possible and I'd really appreciate being able to debug my code properly.

I've also tried adding the two export lines in a "Before Execute" Custom Command but this also doesn't work as it seems these commands are executed in a separate session.

EDIT:
I also tried adding the export commands into the .bashrc file in the ~ directory, to no avail. It seems MonoDevelop runs the command line under a separate context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using absolute paths instead of relative paths.

Comment: I didn't try this but I tried changing the relative paths slightly and it works. I didn't realise that the relative path starts from the location of the .exe Thanks for your correct solution!